# My custom QML gives error: "Cannot assign to non-existent property"

Tags: qt, plugins, qml

Here is my .h file:

```
#ifndef FDR_TCPSOCKET_H
#define FDR_TCPSOCKET_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>


class FDR_TCPSocket : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QTcpSocket* _socket;

    FDR_TCPSocket(QObject* parent = Q_NULLPTR){
        // Create the socket object.
        _socket = new QTcpSocket(parent);

        // Add events to the socket.
        addEvents();
    }

    void addEvents(){
        _socket->connect(_socket, &QTcpSocket::connected, [=]{
            emit Connected();
        });
    }

signals:
    void Connected();

public slots:
    // ...
};

#endif // FDR_TCPSOCKET_H
```

And here is my QML:

```
import com.fedartech.qmlsockets 1.0
...
FDR_TCPSocket{
        onConnected: { ... } <<<========== GIVES ERROR
}
```

But it gives this error:

> Cannot assign to non-existent property "onConnected"

---

(BTW here is the register:)

```
qmlRegisterType<FDR_TCPSocket>("com.fedartech.qmlsockets", 1, 0, "FDR_TCPSocket");
```

Why is this happening? I really don't know.

**Thanks for your helps!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god... Simple answer.

I changed the `Connected()` signal to the `connected()`. (first letter lowercased)

Now it works...